# How to ensure that jquery.load() will always work when updating notifications?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On stackoverflow I assume the stackexchange notifications are being reloaded with jquery.load() or jquery.ajax() every 10-15 seconds.
However when I tested this, every few times it returned an error within the google chrome console.

So is there a way to optimize this so it will work everytime? And is it a good idea to pressure the database every 10-15 seconds like stackoverflow does to reload notifications?

This is my function

```
function reloadnotifications() {
    a1 = $("#msgrfrsh");
    a2 = $("#mybadrfrsh");
    a3 = $("#yrpgrfrsh");
    $.ajax({
        url: '/notify.php?a',
        cache: 'false',
        success: function(response){
            a1.html(response)
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: '/notify.php?b',
        cache: 'false',
        success: function(response) {
            a2.html(response)
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: '/notify.php?c',
        cache: 'false',
        success: function(response) {
            a3.html(response)
        }
    });
    n = notifications();
    if (n>0) {
        //n is past zero, new notifications needed.
        if ($("#newnotifications").css('opacity') == 1) {
            //opacity is equal to 1, so refresh IF n is higher than current value.
            if (n > parseInt($("#newnotifications").html())) {
                $('#newnotifications').css({'opacity':'0','margin-top': '-55px'})
                .html(notifications())
                .animate({'margin-top': '-16px','opacity':'1'});
            } else {
                // leave it for now
            }
        } else {
            //notifications is already invisible, so fade it in. IF the members bar height is 28px
            if ($("#chat").height() == '28px') {
                $('#newnotifications').css({'opacity':'0','margin-top': '-55px'})
                .html(notifications())
                .animate({'margin-top': '-16px','opacity':'1'});
            } else{
                //leave it for now
                alert("we got here");
            }
        }
    } else {
        //notifications have all been read, so a fade out is neccessary.
        $('#newnotifications').animate({'opacity':'0','margin-top': '-55px'});
    }
//thats the end!
  }
  setInterval("reloadnotifications()",15000);
```

Comment: Please post what code you have so far.

Comment: There is no way to ensure that it will work each time.  If someone shuts off their Internet connection it will of course stop working.

Comment: Stack Exchange uses [web sockets](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155637/201429) for it's rep counter

Comment: Are you simply using a `setInterval` to run this function?

Comment: yes, is that bad? @Nunners

Comment: Not necessarily, can you please supply us the code that calls this function, also you seem to have missed the end of the function.

Comment: Check out my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353629/notifications-without-reloading-the-page-like-facebook-or-google-plus-notificat/19353768#19353768  They probably use websockets instead

Comment: @anOG How does it work on IE9 since websockets doesn't run on anything less than 10?  Ref. http://caniuse.com/websockets

Comment: @user1477388 i really hope people aren't using under IE10. everything below ie10 is shocking and ie10 is pretty bad aswell

Comment: What's the actual question here?

Comment: @ben I assume it uses long polling as a backup, but just curious.

Comment: @user1477388 Presumably they have a check for unsupported versions and use AJAX (or maybe nothing) in such a case. I can't say I've ever visited stack overflow on IE<10